# How to check a text is being displayed in Karate?

Tags: javascript, karate, gui-testing

I want to assert that after clicking a feedback form, text not being displayed.

I tried this :

- def visible = script("//div[@class='feedback-wrapper']//textarea", "function(e) { return
  $(e).is(':visible')}")
  And match visible == false

Exception is:
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: $ is not defined

Comment: Any reason why script() was used here to verify for the object when a karate in-built function **exists** available? You can achieve the same using * var elem = exists("//div[@class='feedback-wrapper']//textarea"). More documentation can be found at https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#exists

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that is not working.

Comment: then you have missed something. every UI is different and it is impossible for anyone to help unless we can see the same app you are trying to test. I have no suggestions other than "read the docs"